# Editing Web Map attachments

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing, arcgis-portal, feature-service, attachments

I have editing permission for a web map created by a GIS analyst who is no longer with my company. It is located in an enterprise portal and uses feature service layers that are also in the portal. I've been able to make some edits by downloading the web map and opening it in ArcGIS Pro. However, there have been other edits I can't make. I can't edit attachments on one of the layers (I can see that attachments are enabled. I can open the attribute table and view the path to the attachment. I can also see the jpg listed as an Attachment in the attribute pane but can't remove/upload). I'm wondering if I need to be editing the map in another location, either the developer portal or through the REST API on the enterprise portal.